# how to solve this in C?

Tags: c

There's an N number of people entering in the theater and for each of them we know the exact time of entering and exiting. 
Print the largest number of people that were in the theater at the same time and in which period.

Comment: What have  you tried

Comment: start with main().

Comment: @hyde - That was for the OP.

Comment: @Acme ok, thought it might be that too, but the tone of the message transmits poorly over plain text.

Answer (score 6):

Since you don't have any code yet, I'm going to assume that you are stuck on the algorithm. Here is the obvious way to solve this problem.

1. Create a list of all events, entry and exit.
2. Order that list by time.
3. Walk over the list maintaining a count of how many people are in the theater.
4. When you encounter an enter event, increment the count. When you encounter an exit event, decrement the count.
5. Keep track, whilst walking the list, of the largest value of the count that you have observed.
6. When you have walked the entire list, output the largest value that you observed.

It should be obvious to you how to extend this approach to keep track also of the times at which the count was at its peak value.

I'm not going to write the code for you since that would get in the way of your learning.